# "He is much strong now" or "He is much stronger now"

Tags: adjectives

Could i know pls, If I have to use "much" should i say "strong/adjective" or stronger/comparative"?

"He is much strong now" or "He is much stronger now"

Comment: What do you mean, "*if I have to use much*"? Why do you have to use "much"? Also, do you want to say "He is very strong now" or "He is a lot stronger now"?

Comment: @gotube i want to use "much" with strong/stronger. I know the sentences you provided are understandable but I am particulary curious about using "much"

Comment: So, are you looking for the rules about using "much" with adjectives? There are no special rules for "much" + "strong". It's the same with every adjective

Comment: @gotube  yes I am asking about rule.What i understood is that we could either use "strong" or "stronger" with "much".Am i right in interpreting you?

Comment: We say _much stronger_, not _much strong_. [This page](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers) may be helpful. (Look for _'Much with comparative adjectives and adverbs: much older, much faster'_)

Comment: In basic English, _much_ is always used with the **comparative** form of an adjective. (There are expressions like _much-loved_, but as a language learner you can forget those for now.)

Comment: "Much strong" is the type of mangling of English you can find in the [doge memes](https://memegenerator.net/instance/76721274/real-doge-much-strong-so-wow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

much + *comparative form* is the standard way of using that phrase.

Much stronger, much better, much prettier, much worse, etc.

There are exceptions to this, but as a general thumb rule, you use comparative form.